# How do I process a List of Maps in a subtemplate in JMustache?

Tags: java, templates, mustache

I've been teaching myself JMustache and I'm attempting to send a List of Maps to a sub-template. I have the following Java test:

```
@Test
public void testWithNestedPartial() {
    final WeakHashMap<String, Object> parameters = new WeakHashMap<>();
    parameters.put("start", "hello");

    final List<Map<String, String>> subParameterList = new ArrayList<>();

    WeakHashMap<String, String> subParameters = new WeakHashMap<>();
    subParameters.put("greek", "alpha");
    subParameters.put("numeric", "1");
    subParameterList.add(subParameters);

    subParameters = new WeakHashMap<>();
    subParameters.put("greek", "beta");
    subParameters.put("numeric", "2");
    subParameterList.add(subParameters);

    parameters.put("sub", subParameters);

    final Compiler subTemplateLoadingCompiler = Mustache.compiler()
            .withLoader(templateName -> Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(TEST_TEMPLATE_PATH + templateName + ".htmm")));

    final Template template = subTemplateLoadingCompiler.compile("{{start}}\r\n{{> complex-partial}}");
    final String result = template.execute(parameters);

    Assert.assertEquals(result, "hello\r\n• alpha\r\n• 1\r\n• beta\r\n• 2\r\n");
}
```

...with **complex-partial.htmm**:

```
{{# sub.this}}
• {{greek}}
• {{numeric}}
{{/ sub.this}}
```

...with the following result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [hello
• alpha
• 1
• beta
• 2
] but found [hello
• beta
• 2
]
```

If I switch it and put "alpha" and 1 last, it shows "alpha" and 1.

I know I don't have the sub-template written correctly, and I've tried different ways of setting up the parameters therein, but the solution escapes me. How do I write this partial to pass this test?

Comment: Don't you mean `parameters.put("sub", subParameterList)` instead of `parameters.put("sub", subParameters)`? Otherwise the `subParameterList` collection is updated, but never queried.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens Haha, I sure do! Works like a charm now; thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP had a typo.

He meant to use

```
parameters.put("sub", subParameterList)
```

instead of

```
parameters.put("sub", subParameters)
```